# Azure Functions V4 // ServiceBusTrigger and binding properties like Message or MessageReceiver

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on an Azure Function (in-process model, V 4.1) with a ServiceBusTrigger for a queue. The function works fine and gets triggered. The function looks like this:

```
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my-queue", Connection = "myConnectionString", AutoCompleteMessages = true)]
        string myQueueItem, Int32 deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, string messageId)
```

**I now want to be able to get the correlationId that I passed in the message and I want to be able to "Complete()" the message by myself.**

I looked in the docs here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) but did not find any way to bind other parameters like Message, MessageReceiver, etc. Whenever I try to use these, I get a binding exception when the function runs.

These are the relevant packages I am using

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core" Version="1.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.0" />
```

I must be missing something...any  hint is appreciated!

EDIT: After a cleanup, these are the relevant packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="6.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (possible) solution:

Check the source code:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Triggers/ServiceBusTriggerBindingStrategy.cs#L77

Make sure to also name the *parameters* exactly like in the src (the "contract")

- ServiceBusClient client -> works
- ServiceBusClient myclient -> does not work!

This is how my function looks now:

(...,string myQueueItem, Int32 deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, string messageId,
ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, ServiceBusMessageActions messageReceiver, ServiceBusClient client)

Answer (score 5):

> I am working on an Azure Function (in-process model, V 4.1)

You're not.

> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core" Version="1.4.0" />

Based on the NuGet packages you're using, the SDK is out-of-process / Isolated Worker SDK. With Isolated Worker SDK you cannot complete messages yourself. That's only possible with In-Process SDK. Also, SDK specific types such as `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` or `ServiceBusReceiver` are not available either.

Saying that, you can have access to the system and application properties of the messages. You'd need to access [`FunctionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#execution-context) in the following way:

```cs
context.BindingContext.BindingData.TryGetValue("CorrelationId", out var label)
```

If you need to have access to the SDK types or complete the message yourself, you need to use Azure Functions In-Process SDK, `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`.

Comment: Sean, thx so much for your answer.  I am pretty sure though that I am using the in-process model, e.g. there's no Program.cs (https://www.pmichaels.net/2022/02/12/isolated-azure-function-in-net-6/). In addition, you are correct, the package seems like that, but it was just a left-over from some tests I was doing. I removed it using "Remove unused references".
I think I actually tried using FunctionContext (that's where the package came from).

Comment: Also, I created the project in VS 2022 - there's no option to choose the hosting model anymore? I guess the default is in-process and if you want to have isolated process you'd have to change the code by yourself!?

Comment: My answer was based on the information shared in the question. That's where the old Isolated Worker SDK NuGet package came from. Regardless, VS2022 does allow you to select what Functions SDK to use. It's a drop-down box where .NET version shows up when creating a **new Function Application**. Along with that, you chose the SDK version. [Image](https://ibb.co/C8x7Zwy)

Comment: Sean, that's correct ("It's a drop-down box where .NET version shows up when creating a new Function Application."). One has to be a bit careful when creating the function app...

Comment: Regarding the other issue (ServiceBusReceivedMessage or ServiceBusReceiver can't be binded for in-process model): 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'sbr' to type ServiceBusReceiver. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).